# How to set up wifi programmatically in iOS app?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, wifi, apn

How to set up the known wifi with my known account/password in the iOS app ?

I want the user open the app and set up wifi background without letting user know. Can we do that with code ? and how if we can ?

If we can not, is there any alternative solution to resolve this problem with best user experience ?  thanks

Comment: You can't setup wi-fi from your app. From documentation: "If your app accesses the network using the Wi-Fi radios, you must notify the system of that fact by including the UIRequiresPersistentWiFi key in the app’s Info.plist file. The inclusion of this key lets the system know that it should display the network selection dialog if it detects any active Wi-Fi hot spots. It also lets the system know that it should not attempt to shut down the Wi-Fi hardware while your app is running."  
Why do you need it? There is always another solution.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot setup known wifi networks inside your app. What you could do is add the key 'UIRequiresPersistentWiFi' to your app's plist. That will ensure that the system shows a dialog informing the user about the requirement of wifi for the app. If i remember correctly, in case wifi is disabled, the dialog also displays a settings button by default which the user can click and be redirected to the 'Settings' app. HTH.